# MPAndroidChart how to plot line chart with multiple years

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

For plotting my line chart, I am getting data from server which is based on financial year period i.e from April to March. I am plotting month on xAxis and value on yAxis. Now my problem here is I have value for the month of December 2019 and January 2020 but when I plot it on graph, January is shown as the first value and December as last, whereas I want to plot January value after the December value as it is of different year. I get the value of year from the api but I don't understand how do I use it in my graph.

Also I get the values of month as integer value starting from January to December like this

```
if (month == 1f) {
        return getString(R.string.january)
    } else if (month == 2f) {
        return getString(R.string.february)
    } else if (month == 3f) {
        return getString(R.string.march)
    } else if (month == 4f) {
        return getString(R.string.april)
    } else if (month == 5f) {
        return getString(R.string.may)
    }....
```

I am using the above code to get the label for xAxis.

**How can I take year into consideration for plotting graph properly.**

This is how I am creating my dataset

```
values.add(Entry(historyModel.monthId.toString().toFloat(),
      String.format("%.2f",historyModel.collectionAmount.toFloat()).toFloat()))
```

Comment: Can you add more details about how do your create `DataSet`?

Comment: Its not clear how you are setting data to x-axis. If you are using these integer values for x-axis then try starting with april as 1 to march as 12.

Comment: @TarunChauhan I am getting that value from backend and there January is the first month

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman added the code for dataset. I tried appending year that I get from api with the month id when creating data set but with that the problem is for less than 10, month id is single digit and that fails my combining logic

Comment: @VivekMishra x-axis values will be aligned from low to high values as you may know. If you set jan as 1 in the xaxis then you will get jan as the first value. Try to hardcode the value of april as 1 and respectively other months and see if you get the desired output.

Comment: @TarunChauhan is there no other way available? I have the year value from the api . Can that be used somehow ?

Comment: @VivekMishra it's simple. In any line chart, lower values will be close to the origin and higher values will be far from origin. In your case as well you are setting 1 for January since it is the first one(closes) to the origin. Just set your data from April first and use increment numbers from April instead of January.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207150/discussion-between-tarun-chauhan-and-vivek-mishra).